# Dynamic object property javascript

Tags: ecmascript-next, ecmascript-2016

is there a syntax with javascript es6 or es-next to achieve the following behavior

```
let t = {
    text: 'hello world',
    [shouldShow ? ...{'show' : 'test text'} : ''],
    test: 21
}
```

I want that if shouldShow is true the object t should be

```
{
    text: 'hello world',
    show: 'test text',
    test: 21
}
```

and if shouldShow is false the object t will be

```
{
    text: 'hello world',
    test: 21
}
```

I know, I can do that with if/else but I'm asking if there is a syntax that I can use for just one line of code

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this would solve :

In case you want the show property to be there when shouldShow is false, try this:

```
// this would give show:"" when shouldShow is false, else it will give show="test text"
let shouldShow = false;
let t = {
  text: "hello world",
  show: shouldShow ? "test text" : "",
  test: 21
};
```

In case you want it to be removed from the object itself then try this,

```
// this would make show="test text" when shouldShow is true else remove it from "t"
let shouldShow = true;
let t = {
  text: "hello world",
  test: 21
};
t = shouldShow ? { ...t, show: "test text" } : t;
```